# How to get LOC metric for specific user in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

In a project I am asked for providing LOC for my work for the past 3 months. I have never done anything as such and couldn't find on web for something as such. Is there a way to do so ? Code metric analysis doesn't helps.

Comment: Why are they asking for that anyway?

Comment: @PeterBons totally a guess but its performance review time for everyone in my project so maybe a new metric to see who works more or something as such. apart from this no idea.